# Cantor's Art of proposing a question

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, cantor

There is a rather famous quotation of Cantor:

> In mathematics the art of proposing a question must be held of higher value than solving it.

It was in a thesis he defended for his doctoral examination (according to [MacTutor](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Cantor/quotations/)).

The question is: *How* did Cantor defend this thesis? Is there anything written by him about this subject?

Comment: This is a philosophical statement, of the kind which can be only discussed, with no definite conclusion. Many examples can be given in to support or disprove it. Cantor's own work can be certainly used to support this statement.

Comment: Yes, of course. But I did not ask for *some discussion* but if Cantor's arguments are documented somewhere.